# Mastercard Payment integration in IONIC-3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, checkout, mastercard

I am trying to integrate Mastercard payment [MPGS] into iOS and android with the below script. When I call required methods the checkout pop-up pops up on android but not on iOS. Do I need some special permission for iOS?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/51/checkout.js"
        data-error="errorCallback"
        data-cancel="cancelCallback"
        data-afterRedirect="afterRedirect"
        data-complete="completeCallback">
 </script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic only support this plugins for payment methods:https://ionicframework.com/integrations/category/payments

Comment: Work fine with native app. Not with Hybrid. Thats what i know. Wait for someone else answer, maybe I'm wrong.